# Is there a more elegant way to pad a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

So I have a string called `borrowed_book_bitmask` and I want to pad this string with another string both on the left and right.  The padding is defined in some class as a constant. So I have

```
borrowed_book_bitmask = Module1::Model1::BITMASK_PADDING + borrowed_book_bitmask + Module1::Model1::BITMASK_PADDING
```

This syntax is a bit clunky and inelegant.  Is there a better, more succinct way to express the above?

Assume I can't change the variable name and constant name.

Comment: Here I think clunky is best. For clarity, you might write: `pad = Module1::Model1::BITMASK_PADDING`, then `pad+borrowed_book_bitmask+pad`, `"#{pad}#{borrowed_book_bitmask}#{pad}"` or `pad.concat(borrowed_book_bitmask).concat(pad)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [center method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-center)

```
a = "abc"
"abc.center(a.size + 4 * 2)
=> "    abc    "
```

Comment: Essentially you're padding the string with 4 white spaces?  In my case, the padding is another string, not necessarily all white spaces.  Let's say my padding is "foo", how would you pad the string with "foo" using center?  Thank you.

Comment: @ZackXu BTW, `center` accepts second parameter, a string to pad with. `borrowed_book_bitmask.center(borrowed_book_bitmask.length + 2*Module1::Model1::BITMASK_PADDING.length, Module1::Model1::BITMASK_PADDING)` would work.

Answer (score 1):

```
borrowed_book_bitmask.gsub! /\A|\z/, Module1::Model1::BITMASK_PADDING
```

Comment: Nice. I never thought about using `gsub` on an anchor.

Comment: How about:  borrowed_book_bitmask.gsub! /^|$/, Module1::Model1::BITMASK_PADDING

Comment: @ZackXu Whether you want it to fail on strings, containing `\n`, feel free to go with `/^|$/`.

Comment: Maybe it's just me but this looks more like obfuscation than elegance. It takes far more mental effort and knowledge to understand this snippet than it does to read the OP's original version.

Someone with no experience in ruby could immediately understand the original, while they would have to crack open the documentation on gsub and patterns for this. Typing out the Google search for that documentation already took longer than parsing the original.

Am I missing something? Is there an advantage to this method that outweighs the great cost to simplicity/readability?

Comment: @curiousinternals ruby is the language invented for developers, not for accountants. If anybody has problems reading the above, I’d suggest them to switch to COBOL instead. In our team, we use ruby to make it explicit, assuming everybody is _familiar_ with ruby syntax and parses stuff like `%|a b c|.map &:Kernel.method(:Array)` on the fly, answering what the snippet produces in less than 10ms.

Comment: @mudasobwa Thanks for telling me how great your team is, but I'm afraid not everyone has as much control over the knowledge of their team members as your team, nor the ability to guarantee who may be lumped with dealing with our code far in the future.

However, let's assume we're dealing with experienced devs: I think that any difference in reading speed between your answer and the OP's would be very small at best and still slightly in favour of the original or Andy Jones' answer. How does it make an experienced dev's life easier?

Would your reasoning still hold with a less ideal team?

Comment: @curiousinternals Original Andy Jones’ answer creates a redundant local variable and three intermediate `String` objects because `String#+` is not mutating the object, but produces the new one instead. Even `String#<<` would be a gigantic step towards improvement. The reasoning is not about the greatness of a team; the reasoning is about **I do not care about those developers**, who simply does not bother to learn a syntax to read it fluently. There are many great jobs all around, but while anybody is claiming they are _developers_, they must read this on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "pad"? Always adding the same strings on each side?

```
"#{Module1::Model1::BITMASK_PADDING}#{borrowed_book_bitmask}#{Module1::Model1::BITMASK_PADDING"}
```

What do you mean by "elegant"? Interpolation is vaguely more elegant than concatenation (and more performant IIRC, which I might not). If `borrowed_book_bitmask` is a method then you could embed this in a method, or use a decorator to encapsulate the functionality.

Comment: By "pad" I mean concatenate on both ends.  By "elegant" by I mean shorter and more clear.  It seems to me that in this case concatenation is stylistically cleaner (you're using # { } when I only need to use +).  Maybe my syntax can't be improved further, but just wonder if there's a better way out there.  Thank you.

Comment: @ZackXu Just interpolate or concatenate. That's about as clear as it gets. I might put the constant into a shorter local variable for legibility, but most likely I'd move the functionality into a well-named method and ignore it for the rest of my life. IMO you're over-thinking a trivial implementation.

Comment: “Elegant” should probably always include DRY principle. I doubt the solution with very long variable name, repeated twice on the same line may be considered elegant.

Comment: @mudasobwa I think the focus on making simple string concatenation "elegant" is completely misplaced. The simplest solution in this case is also the most communicative. Once it's moved into a method the mainline code *is* elegant, regardless of the underlying, barely-important implementation.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes, I generally agree with you and I would implement this exactly as you’ve suggested; but since “elegant” is a part of question... :)

Comment: perhaps it's impossible to make it shorter without making it less clear in intent.

Comment: @ZackXu The `gsub` version isn't fundamentally less clear in intent, but even the anchor trick, I'd still do a double-take when reading through the code. It's just my opinion, but I don't think it's worth it, and wrapping it up in a method keeps the mainline code cleaner anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the inelegance comes from the repetition of the module parameter; I keep having to visually parse two long terms to check that they are the same.

```
pad = Module1::Model1::BITMASK_PADDING
borrowed_book_bitmask = pad + borrowed_book_bitmask + pad
```

...too obvious? Maybe that's only more elegant for me.